# How to build an HttpResponseHeaders for the FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, http-headers, fakeiteasy

I'm using C# and I need to Test one of my methods that accept System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders as a parameter. We're using FakeItEasy for the test.

But it seems that the HttpResponseHeaders - does not have the construcotr (and it's sealed), and it uses HttpHeader as base. HttpHeader - has constructor but the Header property only allows get.

Is there a way to build dummy/fake HttpResponseHeaders or HttpResponseMessage and preset the required Header value in it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

FakeItEasy [can't fake a sealed class](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/#what-types-can-be-faked), [nor create a Dummy out of one that doesn't have an accessible constructor](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dummies/#how-are-the-dummies-made), but you could try this:

```
var message = new HttpResponseMessage();
var headers = message.Headers;
headers.Add("HeaderKey", "HeaderValue");
```

Just because the `Headers` are get-only doesn't mean you can't mutate the list.

Answer (score 1):

I used reflection to create a `HttpResponseHeaders` object:

```
    static HttpResponseHeaders CreateHttpResponseHeaders()
    {
        var myType = typeof(HttpResponseHeaders);
        var types = Array.Empty<Type>();
        var constructorInfoObject =
            myType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, types, null);

        return (HttpResponseHeaders) constructorInfoObject.Invoke(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the solution offered by [@Blair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61331733/5407878) for my unit test for a Sendgrid method.

```
var fakeResponse = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
var fakeResponseHeader = fakeResponse.Headers;
fakeResponseHeader.Add("X-Message-Id", "123xyz");
var response = new SendGrid.Response(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted, null, fakeResponseHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection in .Net 6/7/8

```
    private static HttpResponseHeaders CreateHttpResponseHeaders()
    {
        var constructorInfoObject = typeof(HttpResponseHeaders)
            .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new [] { typeof(bool) }, null);

        return (HttpResponseHeaders) constructorInfoObject!.Invoke(new object?[] { false });
    }
```